# how can I add text fields and input into BootstrapDialog?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-dialog

I want to add text fields and inputs inside this modal, but BootstrapDialog doesnt allow me to do it, how can I do it without change the library? by the way can I use $.ajax(); inside?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_item">New item</button>
```

jquery

```
$('#add_item').on('click',function(){
    BootstrapDialog.confirm({
        message: 'Hi Aaron Imperial'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [examples](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/):

```
BootstrapDialog.confirm({
    title: 'Example',
    message: $('<input type="text">')
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbcmutvw/2/).

Comment: can I put mutiples inputs?

Comment: @azdejo Yes.  `message: $('<input type="text"><input type="text">')`

Comment: how could I put a form inside this modal?

Comment: how can I insert my own form on this modal? do I have to use the divs that bootstrap do  the simple modal

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Modal Title',
            message: $('<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Try to input multiple lines here..."></textarea>'),
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Button name',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                hotkey: 13, // Enter.
                action: function() {
                    alert('You pressed Enter.');
                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Java Script Also Its Working Easyly** TRy Once

```
document.getElementById('DialougeID').innerHTML = '<input type=\"text\"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try It Once Directly Added TextBox Based On Dialouge Box Id**

```
BootstrapDialog.confirm({
$('#dialouge-box-id').html("<input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\"/>");
});
```